# Best way to optimize (python) algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a python algorithm which solves an ODE. Now I noticed that this code is for several different input parameters extremely slow. Thus I profiled the code, and got as result:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

        1    0.004    0.004  429.032  429.032 gnlse.py:153(perform_simulation)
        2    0.001    0.000  429.017  214.508 _ode.py:564(integrate)
        2    0.000    0.000  429.016  214.508 _ode.py:381(integrate)
        2   18.985    9.492  429.016  214.508 _ode.py:1013(run)
    52007   22.260    0.000  410.031    0.008 _ode.py:495(_wrap)
    52007  188.766    0.004  387.243    0.007 gnlse.py:234(GNLSE_RHS)
   208033    1.300    0.000  173.272    0.001 fftpack.py:46(_raw_fft)
   104018   18.316    0.000  108.077    0.001 fftpack.py:195(ifft)
   104015    0.857    0.000   90.410    0.001 fftpack.py:100(fft)
   104015   85.626    0.001   85.626    0.001 {numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.cfftf}
   104018   85.607    0.001   85.607    0.001 {numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.cfftb}
    29108   25.776    0.001   25.776    0.001 {min}
   530887    3.275    0.000    3.275    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
   104034    2.522    0.000    2.522    0.000 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

Which part of the algorithm can be optimized best (can that be answered without the whole code based on the cProfile measurements?)? According to the data I would say the `GNLSE_RHS` function, after the total time spent in this function is most significant.
In this function the `fft`-functions (four times each call) are called. Would it make more sense to make them faster instead of improving the algorithmus in the `GNLSE_RHS`?
The function in question is

```
AT = np.fft.fft( np.multiply( AW , np.exp( simp['linop'] * z)))
IT = np.abs(AT)**2  
if simp['raman'] == True:
    RS = simp['dt']  *  np.fft.fft( np.multiply( np.fft.ifft(IT), simp['RW'] ))
    M = np.fft.ifft( np.multiply( AT,( (1-simp['fr'])*IT +  simp['fr']*RS ) ) )      
else:
    M = np.fft.ifft( np.multiply( AT, IT))
return  1.0j * simp['gamma'] * np.multiply( simp['W'], np.multiply( M, np.exp( -simp['linop'] * z)) )
```

Edit: I do not need a refined algorithm, I rather want to know which part is mostly contributing to the running time, i.e. increasing the speed of which function would improve the overall speed the most?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it right. The `GNLSE_RHS` is clearly your bottleneck.

```
52007  188.766    0.004  387.243    0.007 gnlse.py:234(GNLSE_RHS)
```

The problem - your `percall` is extremely short. I'm guessing that `GNLSE_RHS` is a fortran function being wrapped by `scipy`. If so, it would be tough to streamline that.

My approach to solving the Schrodinger equation (mostly Imaginary Time Propagation) has always been to develop my understanding of the algorithm in Python before opting for a final implementation in C.

Comment: The function you are mentioning is also covered in the question itself, thus no, the function is a complete python function, only calling the fft-function several times.

Answer (score -2):

Use the [DRY (Don't repeat yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.  Look for duplicate code and turn them into variables.

For example, you call `simp['linop']` and `simp['fr']` more than once, which is a dictionary lookup each time.  Instead, set `linop_z = simp['linop'] * z` once and then use `linop_z` each time after that, likewise for `fr = simp['fr']`.

Anything more would require unrolling your equations looking for common multipliers, etc.